# Pulling date and time from Excel to Pandas and combining it to a timestamp

Tags: python, excel, datetime, pandas

Final Edit (hopefully):
Oh my god you solved it! 
After upgrading to Pandas 0.15.2, this solution seems to work:

```
trades['OEDatum'] = (trades[['OEDatum', 'OEUhrzeit']].apply
                         (lambda x: dt.datetime.combine
                          (x['OEDatum'].date(), x['OEUhrzeit']), axis=1))
```

Thank you very much @EDChum and @joris

---

I'm trying to pull some data from an Excelsheet via read_excel into a Pandas dataframe:

```
        Asset    OEDatum OEUhrzeit     ODatum  OUhrzeit L/S  Entrykurs  \
Trade                                                                    
1      EURUSD 2014-06-12  12:00:00 2014-06-12  12:23:09   L     1.2456   
2      USDJPY 2014-11-11  10:15:35 2014-11-11  10:34:50   S   126.6300   
3      EURJPY 2014-12-23  13:15:24 2014-12-23  13:25:45   L   114.4600   
4      GBPJPY 2014-12-23  14:27:36 2014-12-23  14:35:56   S   156.6000
```

the values I'm interested in, have the following data types:

```
OEDatum      datetime64[ns]
OEUhrzeit            object
ODatum       datetime64[ns]
OUhrzeit             object
```

As you can see, Pandas pulled the dates as datetime64 values and the times are an object.

Now I need to combine 'OEDatum' with 'OEUhrzeit' and 'ODatum' with 'OUhrzeit' to timestamps. These timestamps should later be used for searching large tickdata files.

But it's simply not possible for me, to combine the dates with the times...

Among a lot of other tries, I wanted to change the time data to a string and use then "to_datetime":

```
trades.OEUhrzeit.apply(str)
pd.to_datetime(trades.OEUhrzeit, utc=False, format='%H%M%S')
```

but then comes this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python Projekte\Test und Funktionsenwicklung\src\Tupel_und_ATR_Updater.py", line 251, in <module>
    trades_ohne_tupel()
  File "F:\Python Projekte\Test und Funktionsenwicklung\src\Tupel_und_ATR_Updater.py", line 173, in trades_ohne_tupel
    **pd.to_datetime(trades.OEUhrzeit, utc=False, format='%H%M%S')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 320, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg.values, False, format)**
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 313, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\tools.py", line 287, in _convert_listlike
    arg, format, coerce=coerce
  File "tslib.pyx", line 1579, in pandas.tslib.array_strptime (pandas\tslib.c:25541)
ValueError: time data datetime.time(12, 0) does not match format '%H%M%S'
```

So I hope someone could show me a solution for this problem.
Thx in advance.

EDIT: @EDChum you are right I use pandas 0.14.1, numpy 1.8.2 and Python 3.4.2
- think that means I have to update my pandas.......

Comment: I think you don't need the `to_datetime` bit could you try `df['OEDatum'] = df[['OEDatum','OEUhrzeit']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.combine(x['OEDatum'].date(),x['OEUhrzeit']), axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, that's the solution, see my edit. Again thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method would be to convert the time strings to datetime but only take the time portion and then call [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) and call [`datetime.combine`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) to produce your datetime for both columns:

```
In [61]:    
df['OEtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OEUhrzeit']).dt.time
df['OEDatum'] = df[['OEDatum','OEtime']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.combine(x['OEDatum'].date(),x['OEtime']), axis=1)

In [62]:    
df['OUhrtime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['OUhrzeit']).dt.time
df['ODatum'] = df[['ODatum','OUhrtime']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.combine(x['ODatum'].date(),x['OUhrtime']), axis=1)
df

Out[62]:
   Trade   Asset             OEDatum OEUhrzeit              ODatum  OUhrzeit  \
0      1  EURUSD 2014-06-12 12:00:00  12:00:00 2014-06-12 12:23:09  12:23:09   
1      2  USDJPY 2014-11-11 10:15:35  10:15:35 2014-11-11 10:34:50  10:34:50   
2      3  EURJPY 2014-12-23 13:15:24  13:15:24 2014-12-23 13:25:45  13:25:45   
3      4  GBPJPY 2014-12-23 14:27:36  14:27:36 2014-12-23 14:35:56  14:35:56   

  L/S  Entrykurs    OEtime  OUhrtime  
0   L     1.2456  12:00:00  12:23:09  
1   S   126.6300  10:15:35  10:34:50  
2   L   114.4600  13:15:24  13:25:45  
3   S   156.6000  14:27:36  14:35:56
```

**EDIT**

It looks like your time column is already a `datetime.time` object so just the following should work:

```
df['OEDatum'] = df[['OEDatum','OEUhrzeit']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.combine(x['OEDatum'].date(),x['OEUhrzeit']), axis=1)
df['ODatum'] = df[['ODatum','OUhrzeit']].apply(lambda x: dt.datetime.combine(x['ODatum'].date(),x['OUhrzeit']), axis=1)
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I get the following message: 'AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt''

Comment: Please edit any new info into your question, thanks. Also post your pandas, python, numpy version.

Comment: It sounds like you're running a version of pandas older than 0.15.0, can you confirm this

Comment: @EdChum the first line (conversion of OEUhrzeit) is not needed. The time values are already `datetime.time` objects, so the `datetime.combine` already works. @nic that means it will also work with 0.14 if you aren't able to upgrade

Comment: @joris it was unclear to me whether the OEUhrzeit is a `str` dtype or `time` which is why I thought to do the conversion

Comment: yes, that was indeed not clear, but you can see it in the ValueError message in the question